# Rebirth versus genetic recombination

Tags: rebirth

Humans like nearly all other species have their genetic base as a mixture 50:50 from the genes of their father and from the genes of their mother. Each generation represents a new combination of genes from the gene pool of the species. The genetic basis determines to a large amount who we are.

Does this fact contradict the rebirth of individuals?

Comment: Are you defining rebirth as "rebirth of the same genes"? Are two identical twins the same person, or, two different people? As for "who we are", isn't that defined by kamma and/or by dependent origination? Doesn't non-self (anatta) imply that "I am not my genes"? When you say "the rebirth of individuals", where is that phrase (and especially the term, "individuals") defined?

Comment: Question 1: I do not define rebirth as rebirth of the same genes. I define rebirth as rebirth of the same person. But genes determine the scope of a person's potential. Question 2: I consider two twins not identical, even in case they are monozygotic. Because each of both develops different I consider them two different persons. Question 3: The question "Who we are?" refers to a person's characteristics: How he/she introduces and describes him/herself. Would you please post your final questions as a separate question. Thank you

Comment: @jowehler, I suggest you ask following additional questions: "How is the notion of person or individual treated in Buddhism?" (pudgala) and "what is reborn?" (nama-rupa).

Answer (score 5):

This goes back to an argument that was very popular in 19th century: "is person's character inborn or is it a result of upbringing?"...

What is meant by "rebirth" in Buddhism is rebirth of the state of mind. In modern terms we could say that the living brain is only a carrier. So where does our state of mind come from?

Once as I meditated, I realized that some of my typical thoughts came back from my childhood, from my parent's dysfunctional family situation. And the roots of that situation can be traced to my father's childhood, and probably beyond, to his father's life.

Not all of it is passed down the family lines either. Today at least some of my thoughts came from news I read online about the situation in Ukraine. Do you understand? Our state of mind at any moment consists of elements each of which came down a chain of interactions that can be traced back to beginningless times!

Our state of mind is not "one thing", not an entity, there is no "I".  The boundary between inner and outer is a fiction; there is an infinite sea of interacting mental and physical factors.

So why call it rebirth then? Because of *appropriation*. We appropriate a combination of traits as "I", "me", "mine". My country, my family, my childhood, my education, my believe, my values, my principles, my pride etc. Appropriation of these causes rebirth and suffering.

Comment: You define "rebirth := rebirth of state of mind". I think that's not common use of the concept of rebirth. Your concept of rebirth sounds like remembering a thought or reactivating an emotion or having the same thought like some other or having empathy towards others or feel like others felt before.

Comment: I believe that is the common use, at least in Mahayana.

Comment: Mahayana is a wide sphere ... Could you please name a reference. Thank you.

Comment: This is self-evident. Rebirth is not rebirth of body, right? Rebirth is not rebirth of soul, because in Buddhism there is no such entity as "soul" (or atman). Rebirth is not rebirth of "I", because in Buddhism there is none. Then what is reborn? The mind itself is not an entity, it does not have essence -- it is an ability to cognize. So the only thing that remains is the state of mind.

Comment: Andrei, we have a misunderstanding: I asked for a quote concerning your statement about  Mahayana. I did not ask for a chain of indirect reasoning. I would appreciate an explicit reference to a Mahayana text.  On the other hand, referrring to Theravada we have the Maha-sihanada Sutta (MN12). Here Buddha clearly names aspects and particulars of the past lives of a Tathagata like clan, appearance, nutriment, experience of pleasure and pain, life-term. In my opinion, these characteristics are not restricted to mind states.

Comment: When asked what is reborn, Chogyam Trungpa answered "neurosis". In Milindapanha (not Theravada, but an early text), Nagasena says "it's not getting transferred and yet incarnates ... like a poem you learned from your teacher's words" and "it is not this very namarupa that incarnates; with this namarupa performs a deed — whether good or wicked — and through this deed incarnates another namarupa". Even Theravada's Visuddhimagga says "elements of being ... arrive at a new existence: none transmigrated from the last existence, nor are they in the new existence without causes contained in the old"

Comment: Also, for Mahayana proper, check out Dogen's Bendowa. There he speaks at length about this so-called Srenika Heresy.

Comment: Andrei,
from Milindapanha I learn: “It is name (nama) and form (rupa) that is born into the next existence.” If I take nama-rupa as shorthand for the five aggregates then I have the whole person, not only her mental states (samskara).
Apparently one cannot sum up nama-rupa as neurosis like the quote from Chogyam Trungpa. But I can appreciate the joke. From a sociological point of view it contains a grain of truth – unfortunately.
From Dogen’s rejecting the “Srenika heresy” I do not conclude that he supports the view that mental states in separation are reborn.

Comment: True, namarupa is born (not "into the next existence" -- that's bad translation) -- but it's not the same namarupa. As per Milindapanha, the old namarupa dies, the new namarupa is born, and what connects the two is information and causal links. True, it's not just state of mind that is born, it is _state_ of everything. But it is _state_ nevertheless, not entity (like person). If ancients had concept of _in-form-ation_, they would say it is information that incarnates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17814/discussion-between-jo-wehler-and-andrei-volkov).

Answer (score 0):

I was kind of confused and bewildered by the question but I think I understand what your getting at.
I'm sure you know that genes don't have minds to perform karmic intentions.  What genes a being is recombined with upon rebirth depends on the previous morality of the being  (according to the teachings of the Buddha). Of course on another level, what genes a being gets depends on mother and father's genes:

One person is born with genes that give them a body that stays fit no matter what they eat while another person gets an unfit body even though they exercise and eat all the right foods. The Buddha 's teaching here is more at the level of answering the question as to why one person seems naturally rewarded by the genes they were born with while the other seems cursed. So, if we are cursed in this life it is because of bad karma(bad moral action) we made in a past life and if we are blessed it is because of good karma(good moral action) we performed in a past life according to Buddhism.-hope this helps :)

Comment: Of course different people are born with different dispositions for diseases rooted in their genes. But if a person suffers a genetic defect, then I consider it an inhuman behaviour to blame the person for a bad moral action in her past live. Are you sure that such a causal connection exists?

Comment: No one blames anyone, that is just how reality works in Buddhismville.